# How can I detect keyboard opening and closing in compose multiplatform?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, kotlin-multiplatform, jetbrains-compose

All the answers that i saw related to detecting the Keyboard open and close event are specific to android (using the WindowInsets).

Is there a way to get the keyboard open/close event in the shared module in compose multiplatform?

Comment: Keyboards do not open and close in all Compose Multiplatform environments, such as desktop or Web. You may need to determine how iOS handles those events, then create a Multiplatform wrapper around the Android and iOS implementations.